# Como deixa o menu 100% ao dar zoom no navegador?

Tags: css, menu

Galera o que posso fazer para que meu menu continue 100% ao dar zoom no navegador, sem que eu tenha que usar position:fixed... 
Meu menu tem width 100% e um banner de 1024px...(pagina nao é responsiva).

Como está:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
.container{width:100%; height:110px; background-color:#bc0000;}

.banner{width:1024px; height:320px; margin:auto background:url(img/banner.jpg) center;}
```

Obrigado

Comment: Só com essas informações é difícil analisar. Teria que colocar na pergunta mais detalhes do HTML e o CSS.

Comment: Coloque na pergunta tudo que vc tem de CSS e HTML na sua página, ai fica mais fácil pra te ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Adicione o seguinte código ao seu css. Provavelmente o que está acontecendo é que ao dar o zoom as margens e paddings do html e body aumentam também.

```
    html,body{
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
```